# Using GROUP BY in JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am having a @ManyToMany relationship between a Question entity and a Category entity. I want to count the number of questions in each category. How would I do that?

Comment: To be honest I have no Idea where to start. I have started with this: @NamedQuery(name="Cateogory.questionDistribution", query="SELECT c.description, COUNT(c) FROM Category c GROUP BY (....

Comment: It looks like you were close, but the rest of the query would have helped determine that more.

Comment: How is fetch type for Question defined on your Category entity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select count(question.id), category.description 
from Category category
left join category.questions question
group by category.description
```

Comment: Can I ask one more thing, what does this query return? An hashmap? And if so what are the keys that I access the values with? I have never selected just some attributes before.

Comment: It returns a List<Object[]>. Each Object[] has two elements: the count (as a Long) and the description (as a String). See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-select